# Active record model with remote data storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, web-services, activeresource

I want to implement a model "Contact", whose data is not stored in database, but remotely.
The operations on data are done via web service.
The model Contact is related to other models, whose data is stored locally.

Is there any plugin/gem which can take care of this?

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

No plugin or gem needed. See [ActiveResource](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base).

Comment: but the webservice is already implemented. I will be using a gem to interact with the webservice. Will active resource work in this scenario

Comment: I'm sure it would work unless you have very particular needs.

Comment: To be specific, I am using the following webservice: http://dev.cakemail.com/page/cakeengine-api-communication. This uses encrypted xml to communicate.